# create_post in distill: In as.character.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) : as.character(td, ..) no longer obeys a 'format' argument; use format(td, ..)?

Tags: r, web, distillery, r-distill

I am creating a web page in distill. When I try to create a post with the following code

```
distill::create_post("science", collection = "disclosure")
```

Here I tell distill to create a new post called science, in the disclosure section. but i get the following error:

```
In addition: Warning message:
In as.character.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...) :
   as.character(td, ..) no longer obeys a 'format' argument; use format(td, ..) ?
```

I get rmd to create the post but when I build the website I don't get the post on the page.

Comment: FYI: This issue was already reported on Github: https://github.com/rstudio/distill/issues/488.